# How to compute the Lovász number for the given graph in Mathematica?

Tags: programming, graphs-and-networks, linear-algebra

Here is a graph whose adjacency matrix is

```
m = {
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, 
{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1}, 
{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, 
{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, 
{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 
{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

then how to compute its [Lovász number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lov%C3%A1sz_number) in *Mathematica*? I think this is a common question. Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Here are three ways to do the computation, which is the best one to compile in Mathematica and how?

1.Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph on $n$ vertices. Let $A$ range over all $n*n$ symmetric matrix|symmetric matrices such that $a_{ij}=1$ whenever $i=j$ or $ij∉E$, and let $λ_{max}(A)$ denote the largest eigenvalue of $A$. Then an alternative way of computing the Lovász number of $G$ is as follows:
$$
  \vartheta(G) = \min_A \lambda_\text{max}(A).
$$

2.The following method is dual to the previous one. Let $B$ range over all $n*n$ symmetric positive semidefinite matrix such that $b_{ij'}=0$ for every $ij ∈ E$ and $Tr(B)=1$. Here $Tr$ denotes trace  (the sum of diagonal entries) and $J$ is the $n*n$ matrix of ones. Then
$$
  \vartheta(G) = \max_B \operatorname{Tr}(BJ).
$$
Note that $Tr(BJ)$ is just the sum of all entries of $B$.

3.The Lovász number can be computed also in terms of the complement graph $\bar{G}$. Let $d$ be a unit vector and $V = (v_i | i ∈ V)$ be an orthonormal representation of $\bar{G}$. Then
$$
  \vartheta(G) = \max_{d,V} \sum_{i \in V} (d^\mathrm{T} v_i)^2.
$$

Though PlatoManiac provided a helpful link, that way can not go through on my computer.

Comment: Here is a code http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.de/2011/03/computing-lovasz-theta-function.html

Comment: @PlatoManiac Thanks a lot! But it is too hard to install that package for me. Is there any other way?

Comment: @PlatoManiac I tried to install one needed file [cvxopt](http://abel.ee.ucla.edu/cvxopt/download.php) but failed in my ubuntu 13.04. So, some other way may be better for me. Thanks!

Comment: @EdenHarder Consider that very likely it is considerably harder to write the function from scratch than to install the package.

Comment: @Szabolcs Yeap, but there are too many obstacles in the way to install that package. I try the random method but it seems not efficient.

Comment: @Szabolcs My OS is Ubuntu and I cannot get over this step: *copy mathlink.framework (in /Applications/Mathematica.app/SystemFiles/Links/MathLink/DeveloperKit/CompilerAdditions/) to /Library/Frameworks directory* for I cannot find the file *mathlink.framework* and the directory */Library/Frameworks*. Any help will be appreciated!